# g++ error regarding undefined reference to typedef

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-construction, g++, typedef

i am trying to compile a simple test program, and one of the header files i am including has the following typedef

```
typedef const char* CharConst;
typedef unsigned int MyBool;
```

later in the header file, some functions are defined using this typedef.  stuff like:

```
MyBool add_att(CharConst attr, const char*);
```

i am getting an error when i try to make a call to this function, with a call like:

```
CharConst myconst = "some text";
const char* more_text = "more text";
add_att(myconst, more_text);
```

the error is: undefined reference to `MyClass::add_att(char const*, char const*)'

it seems that the compiler doesn't like the fact that the first argument has been typedef'd in the header file. but it doesn't mind the MyBool.  the compiler only complains about the CharConst definition.

is there any easy way to fix this?  any clues or hints on what i can do?  i'm running gcc version 4.6.2

Comment: Show the function signature in definition. Also never use `typedef` on pointers types, it is confusing as well as such problems always creep up with it.

Comment: Did you include the header file that declared/defined `add_att()` in the file that you were trying to call that function? Is `add_att()` defined in a lib and you forgot to link to that lib?

Comment: The `typedef` shouldn't make any difference (beyond confusing any humans who try to read the code). It looks like either you haven't implemented the function, or you're not linking with the file that contains its implementation.

Comment: yeah, i have an include, or the compiler would be complaining about much more than just this.  as per the libraries, my compile line looks like this: g++ main.cpp myclass.cpp -L/opt/stuff/lib -lstuff   any clues? the lib folder contains libstuff.a, libstuff_c++.a, libstuff_c++.la, and libstuff.la.  do i need a so file in there?

Comment: @jasonmclose: Is the function defined in `myclass.cpp`? Basically, the code you've shown us is just fine. And this isn't the sort of error a compiler that is beyond the toy stage is likely to make, so the chances of it being a compiler problem (already very small mind you) are astronomically tiny. So the error must be in code you haven't shown us, and given the exact error, likely has something to do with linking.

Comment: [Works for me](https://ideone.com/28Lax) -- please provide a complete, minimal program that demonstrates your error. In the process, you may find the error on your own. See http://sscce.org for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error it looks like add_att is a method of a class; I do not see an instance of your class to call the method. Consider this: MyClass *m = new MyClass(); m->add_att(....)

Alternatively, ensure that the function is actually defined, not just prototyped. Also, this may not matter, but during the definition of the function - do you use the typedef in the function arguments? Actually that shouldn't matter... type is the same.

Comment: i've looked further into this.  turns out my version of gcc (which is very new) doesn't play nice with static linking yet, and i need to be statically linking in this library (.a files).  i am recompiling the library to use shared objects (which oddly is not the default way of doing it for this library).  will retry this shortly.

Comment: That could very well be it; However, try to avoid blaming the compiler unless you have tested with another version on the same hardware.

I love blaming the compiler, and drivers (boy do I love blaming the drivers!) But majority of times it is something on your end, or the other library. Try testing with a different version of GCC; Though 4.6.2 worked fine for me (solved more problems than it created lol).

Comment: ok.  this has got to be a problem with how i am trying to compile.

Comment: this is how i am doing it: gcc -o mytest main.cpp MyFile.cpp -L/opt/stuff/lib -lstuff  - shouldn't that work?  there is a libstuff.so file in the lib directory.

Comment: jimminy christmas.  got it fixed.  apparently, there was another library that had to be included BEFORE the -lstuff library.  i had to crawl through the depths of the internet to figure this out.  been searching for around 4 hours now.  thanks to all who wanted to help.  this was one of those things that there was no way for anyone to know, just because of the particular library i was using.  i appreciate the help.